# ostream operator shouldn't be calling overloaded new operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, new-operator

I am reading Thinking in C++ (Vol 1 - Page-597). I just came across with a concept of overloading the global new/delete operator.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
void* operator new(size_t sz) {
    printf("operator new: %d Bytes\n", sz);
    void* m = malloc(sz);
    if(!m) puts("out of memory");
    return m;
}
void operator delete(void* m) {
    puts("operator delete");
    free(m);
}
class S {
    int i[100];
    public:
        S() { puts("S::S()"); }
       ~S() { puts("S::~S()"); }
};
int main() {
    puts("creating & destroying an int");
    int* p = new int(47);
    delete p;
    puts("creating & destroying an s");
    S* s = new S;
    delete s;
    puts("creating & destroying S[3]");
    S* sa = new S[3];
    delete []sa;
}
```

Taking this example it says following :-

> Notice that printf( ) and puts( ) are used rather than iostreams. This
>   is because when an iostream object is created (like the global cin,
>   cout, and cerr), it calls new to allocate memory. With printf( ), you
>   don’t get into a deadlock because it doesn’t call new to initialize
>   itself.

Now to check the correctness of above statement, i included iostream library and also added cout statement in say conttructor in hope of getting an infinite loop as i was expecting cout will call new and it will be infinite loop. But it worked normal. No ambiquity or infinite loop.

Am i missing something here??

Comment: can you show your modified code?

Comment: I suspect that the book meant to say "it *may* call new to allocate memory".

Comment: Also note that the book talks about the *creation* of the `cin`, `out`, and `cerr` objects, not their use.